# Loading audio file to Speech recognition module for Python directly from SFTP server (using Paramiko SFTPClient)

Tags: python, speech-recognition, sftp, paramiko

I want to preface this with the fact that I am still very much a noob at Paramiko, so this might all be completely impossible.

I want to open a `.wav` file on a server from my computer in order to do some speech recognition on it. To do this, I create a Transport with Paramiko and use it to open the audio file on the server. Then I set this file as my source and use SpeechRecognition to print whatever's being said in the audio file. However, when I open the file located in `remotefilepath`, it is no longer recognised as an audio file, since I get the error message `AssertionError: Source must be an audio source`. Printing `type(file)` I get `<class 'paramiko.sftp_file.SFTPFile'>`.

I want to just open the file on the server and do the speech recognition on it without having to first save the file onto my own computer. Is there any way for me to do this? Any help/advice is very much appreciated

```
import paramiko
import speech_recognition as sr

remotefilepath = /path/to/file.wav
server_ip = 12.34.567.8
server_port = 22
transport = paramiko.Transport((server_ip, server_port))
transport.connect(username="foo", password="bar")
print "Connected to transport"
sftp = transport.open_sftp_client()
file = sftp.open(remotefilepath)

#print type(file)

r = sr.Recognizer()

with file as source:
    r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
    audio = r.record(source)
    try:
        text = r.recognize_google(audio)
        print "You said: {}".format(text)
    except:
        print "Sorry, I could not understand."

file.close()
sftp.close()
transport.close()
print "Closed transport. Ending program"
```

Python 2.7 on Windows 10.

Comment: Which method throws the error? + Does your `Recognizer` class have any documentation?

Comment: @MartinPrikryl `r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)` throws the error. This is the documentation I found: https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`adjust_for_ambient_noise`](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst#recognizer_instanceadjust_for_ambient_noisesource-audiosource-duration-float--1---none) takes an implementation of [`AudioSource`](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst#audiosource) as an argument. You are passing file-like object instead.

I believe you can use [`AudioFile`](https://github.com/Uberi/speech_recognition/blob/master/reference/library-reference.rst#audiofilefilename_or_fileobject-unionstr-ioiobase---audiofile) implementation of `AudioSource` instead. `AudioFile` can be created with file-like object:

```
with sftp.open(remotefilepath) as file:
    with AudioFile(file) as source:
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try copying file from source to local and start processing it.

```
sftp.get(filepath, localpath)
```

Comment: I know this is a possibility, but as I said, I want to just open the file on the server and do the speech recognition on it without having to first save the file onto my own computer.